# Exception in VS code while debugging nodejs code using ES7 and babel

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-core

Every time this exception occurs when I start to debug the code in VS code. It's annoying, it is failing in babel-core module, I have no Idea what is going wrong.

Exception has occurred: TypeError

```
 TypeError: Number.prototype.toFixed requires that 'this' be a Number
at Object.toFixed (<anonymous>)
at /Users/Development/projects/inventory-manager-api/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.number.to-fixed.js:63:12
at module.exports (/Users/Development/projects/inventory-manager-api/node_modules/core-js/modules/_fails.js:3:14)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Development/projects/inventory-manager-api/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.number.to-fixed.js:61:26)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
```